# Displaying the data from the function

Tags: javascript, html, json

Create a JavaScript function named display_data that has two parameters. The first parameter will be a string containing a JSON blob. The second parameter will be a boolean. Start by using the JSON library to convert the first parameter into a usable JavaScript Object.

Next get the HTML element whose id is "data". This HTML element is a div If the second parameter is equal to true, write the value associated with the Object's ​"total" key into the div. If the second parameter is equal to false, write the value associated with the Object's "average" key into the  div.

I tried the code below but I'm not sure If I'm following the directions correctly, I can't make any test cases until online grader is available next week.

```
function display_data(json,boolean){
  var parseData = JSON.parse(json);
  var getElem = document.getElementById("data");
  if (boolean == true){
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = parseData;
  }
  else if (boolean == false){
    document.getElementById("average").innerHTML = parseData
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `getElem`?

Comment: Yeah, I'm really confused on where I have put that in the code. My idle is telling me that I'm not using it so that's kinda obvious. To be completely honest, I can't fully understand the question. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it means that you will get the data associated with "total" or in the json to the <div id="data"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base on what I understand you should get the value from the JSON.

```
function display_data(json,boolean){
  var parseData = JSON.parse(json);
  var getElem = document.getElementById("data");
  if (boolean == true){
    getElem .innerHTML = parseData.total;
  }
  else if (boolean == false){
    getElem .innerHTML = parseData.average;
  }
}
```

I think this is the correct approach,

Comment: Ahh.. I see, this totally make sense but just to make sure I'm going to look at more feedbacks. Thanks.

Comment: at it's core, there is no need. the exercise is fairly straight forward when you understand it. Took me a few minutes also to get the point, but beyond that, this is the desired result. As any function, it can be written in multiple ways to achieve the same result. But this works and is valid. Yet, feel free to see how it could be done differently.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path.

'If the second parameter is equal to false, write the value associated with **the Object's** "average" **key** into the div.'

```
function display_data(json,boolean){
  var parseData = JSON.parse(json);
  var getElem = document.getElementById("data");
  if (boolean){
    getElem.innerHTML = parseData.total
  } else {
    getElem.innerHTML = parseData.average
  }
}
```

PS: no need to provide else if for true/false only.

Comment: Very similar to @Francis ask question, thank you for the PS.

Comment: seen the post after I've submitted my answer, but it's basically the same. Glad you've found the help you needed. Best of luck!